# How to use a Spring Boot enabled library inside a old-school spring server

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**tl/dr** (How) Is it possible to use a jar library, that uses Spring Boot for configuration in a non Spring Boot (regular old-school Spring) server.

We have the problem, that we have a Spring server, that is from the pre-Boot times and we want to create a new library for it. We would like to use Spring Boot in the library (i.e. `@EnableAutoConfiguration` for configuration). To include the library we have put an spring.xml into the library that enables `component-scan` inside the library. The classes inside the library use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@EnableWebSecurity` to enable configuration and security.

If we include now the library into our server and `import` the XML file from the library into the server's XML file, only parts of the configuration are working. The `@RequestMapping`s in the library are working and the interfaces are available. However Spring security fails to register it's default filter chain, leading to ugly errors, where the regular Spring Boot config should already work with `AnonymousAuthorizationFilter`, etc.

We debugged, that the `FilterRegistrationBean` in spring security is never configured when running that way (and is, if we are running as a Spring Boot application).

- So is there a common way how to deal with Spring Boot enabled libraries inside old-school Spring servers?
- Is placing a single XML to enable component-scan in the library and importing this XML inside the main server's XML the correct way to include Spring Boot libraries (and how would be the best way, if the server *would* use Spring Boot itself)?
- Does anyone know of the issue with a missing Spring Security filter chain?

PS: I know that we can add the required filters manually. However if we would do that, we would anyway get rid of Spring Boot completely in the library, so this question mainly aims for how to do it with Spring Boot. Of course if it is the wrong way to enable Spring Boot inside a library, please also mention that :-)

Comment: Have you tried leaving the spring-boot application as it is, but making your parent application a parent of the spring boot application using `.parent(...)` on `SpringApplicationBuilder`?

Comment: @IlyaNovoseltsev I haven't uses that, because we let us autowire the `ApplicationContext` in the main server and inside a `Controller` in the library and it was exactly the same ApplicationContext instance, so I assumed, that this wasn't the problem.